# Long username partially overlaps with site logo in chat profile popup

Tags: bug, design, chat, chat-profile

For users with rather long names, the username partially overlaps with the site logo in the chat profile popup:

[image]

Tested in the latest Firefox and Chrome on macOS Mojave.

Comment: yea, same for me on latest Firefox and Windows 10. Just 1 extra character (which new SO users who get names in the range of 12000000+ now) would make the entire word carry over to the next line, but this is just enough characters to stay on the first line and the last symbol gets under the site logo